# Why does CloudWatch only accept Dimension as Collections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Looking into the CloudWatch api I spotted the following case:

GetMetricStatisticsRequest object has this method:
"setDimensions(Collection dimensions)
A list of dimensions describing qualities of the metric."
[link to API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/model/GetMetricStatisticsRequest.html#setDimensions(java.util.Collection))

I therefore assumed that one can pass an Array of Dimensions and get the Datapoints for each dimension. So, an example would be:

```
    ArrayList<Dimension> dimensions = new ArrayList<Dimension>();
    Dimension firstDimension = new Dimension();
    firstDimension.setName("InstanceId");
    firstDimension.setValue(instanceId1);
    dimensions.add(firstDimension);
    Dimension secondDimension = new Dimension();
    secondDimension.setName("InstanceId");
    secondDimension.setValue(instanceId2);
    dimensions.add(secondDimension);
    metricStatisticRequest.setDimensions(dimensions);
    ...
    GetMetricStatisticsResult results = cloudWatchClient.getMetricStatistics(metricStatisticRequest);
    for(Datapoint dataPoint : results.getDatapoints())
    {
        // do something with datapoints...
        // here I get all the datapoints, of both firstDimension and secondDimension are mixed up
    }
```

That indeed works, only that there's no way to identify which Datapoint belongs to which Dimension: the returned Datapoints collection contains ALL the Datapoints for the metric.

If it's impossible to distinguish between the datapoints then there's no reason to pass more than one Dimension to GetMetricStatisticsRequest. Why, therefore, does CloudWatch API only receive Collections? What's the point of having more than one dimension in a matric? Am I missing something...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the concept dimensions.

In CloudWatch every metric has to have a Namespace, and a Metric name. It can also have up to ten dimensions - these are additional attributes of metrics, name/value pairs that helps you to uniquely identify them.

E.g per-instance EC2 metrics have only "InstanceId" dimension, but per-service billing metrics have two dimensions: "Service" and "Currency".

More about CloudWatch metric concepts here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudwatch_concepts.html

So probably what you want to do is send 2 GetMetricStatistics calls, one with InstanceId=ID1 and the other with InstanceID=ID2